# Issue with setup of Zend framework on localhost

Tags: apache, zend-framework2

I have just started to learn Zend and referring to 
http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/user-guide/skeleton-application.html
to create my first application.

I followed all the steps for creating the Virtual host but have been unsuccessful.

My Code:

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80>
   ServerName zendapp.localhost
   DocumentRoot C:\Program Files\Zend\Apache2\htdocs\zendapp\public
   SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "development"
   <Directory C:\Program Files\Zend\Apache2\htdocs\zendapp\public>
      DirectoryIndex index.php
      AllowOverride All
      Order allow,deny
      Allow from all
   </Directory>
 </VirtualHost>
```

After adding this code in C:\Program Files\Zend\Apache2\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf, I restarted the Server and typed "zendapp.localhost"

I get a message saying "could not find zendapp.localhost"

Can anyone help I have been struggling for some time.
As I said I am extremely new to Zend.

Comment: try `<virtualHost *: 80>` instead of the fixed ip.

Comment: Hey cptnk thanks for replay but earlier it was * after some google search suggestions I used IP address

Comment: did you modified your hosts in C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc ? And activated rewrite module for apache2 ?

Comment: Adding on to what Hooli said: make sure you have a line in your hosts file aliasing zendapp.localhost to your machine, otherwise your browser has no way to know where to go!

Comment: Thanks a lot Hooli and STLMikey your suggestion were useful...Using your suggestion I found some links and solved the problem...Thanks a lot